# What is the Command to get the command history in Atom editor console window?

Tags: console, julia, atom-editor

I am using Atom editor with `uber-juno` package installed as Julia IDE. I would like to know if there is any way to get all the list of commands typed in console window instead of going through it using the up arrow or down arrow.

Like in linux we can type `history` in terminal to get all the history of commands typed in the terminal. Kindly let me know if there is a way to achieve this.

Thank You.

Comment: I'd love this too. I don't think the functionality exists, though.

Comment: X-ref: https://github.com/JunoLab/atom-ink/issues/105 if you only want to browse the history, type `cat .julia_history` in shell mode.

Comment: @Gnimuc Thank you for the link. Guess `esc` + `up arrow` seems like way to go about it as of now.

Answer (score 4):

While there's no 'julia function' that does this, you can easily slip into shell mode (as Gnimuc hinted) from *within* the julia REPL by pressing `;` before typing a command. This transforms your julia promt from `julia>` to `shell>`.

Then you can issue the following command:

```
less .julia_history
```

Since this also contains timestamps and other info, if you *just* want the commands, you can grep out lines starting with a `#` comment:

```
grep "^#" .julia_history -v | less
```

This pretty much has the same effect as `history` in bash / matlab / etc.

This also has the added advantage that you can then use all the functionality provided by `less` (including searching) right from within your terminal.

---

<sub>PS: and after having typed this once you won't have to remember it, because you'll be able to call it easily next time by typing `;grep` and pressing the up-arrow :p  (though as far as shell commands / grepping goes, these are fairly straightforward commands)</sub>

Comment: This is a really cool hack. Now we just need someone to PR this to atom-julia-client :-)

Comment: I see this file has moved to ~/.julia/logs/repl_history.jl